# What happens when you scream out of your window in Sweden at 10 PM

Tags: field-recording, stock-effects

Anyone living in Stockholm? I would definitely try and record this :)

http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=c26_1357935775

Greetings,

Arnoud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fantastic!

I've found this somewhere on the www:

*If you screamed as loud as you could from a window tonight, you’d probably receive several invitations to shut the heck up, but but not in the Flogsta neighborhood of Uppsala, Sweden. As this video creepily demonstrates, this community has a daily ritual called "the Flogsta scream" in which each night at 10 p.m., students scream collectively from windows, balconies and rooftops. Its origin is debated: Some say it’s a stress relief technique that emerged during exam times and became a daily habit. Others say it began as a remembrance of a student’s suicide in the 1970s. We're betting some outsiders might admit that the first time they heard it, they needed new pants.*

Comment: "Scream during exam time" is definitely credible. That would happen at least once during each finals week in college.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_week

Answer (score 1):

Very cool and little creepy too reminds me of the experimental noise group [Stalaggh](http://youtu.be/br5tyuEUBWE) that apparently according to them took mental patients with homicidal urges into a chapel and recorded their wild screaming and yelling.

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha, I must try it! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Yep it's a university thing here...

Tuesdays at ten at some of the housing areas connected to some universities. 
Should be recordable. 
I have to much of a cold ATM to do it right now. 
Should it be recorded during winter/snow (dampened and less apparent reflections) or wait until the snow is gone?